# .is() not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, practicing with a slideshow and trying to make it repeat. For some reason `if ( last.is(active) )` is never returning true. In inspector I can see that the last child is getting the active ID. Is this not how it's meant to be used? `if (active != last)` didn't work either.

<kbd>[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9ju9fg3/)</kbd>

JS

```
function changeImage() {
  var active = $('#active');
  var first = $('#slideshow:nth-child(1)');
  var last = $('#slideshow:nth-last-child(1)');
  if ( last.is(active) ) {
    var next = first;
  } else {
    var next = active.next();
  }
  next.attr('id', 'active');
  active.attr('id', 'inactive');
}

setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

Markup

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <img id="active" src="https://i.imgur.com/8iOuvtf.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Wi8mlH2.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MNhgqco.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow img {display: none;} 
#slideshow #active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Use a string selector not a referenced jq object. And preferably, swap a class not an ID which is quite purposeless here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this fiddle together for you.
https://jsfiddle.net/76xg0d7L/

It is much easier to work with classes than IDs in this situation. I have modified your changeImage() function.

```
function changeImage() {
    var $next = $('.slide.active').removeClass('active').next('.slide');

    if ($next.length) {
        $next.addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $('.slide:first').addClass('active');
    } 
}

setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

I've also update your CSS to select the active class, as opposed to the ID.

```
#slideshow img {display: none;} 
#slideshow .active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if this works for you.

Comment: Chaining is kinda new to me, so is `var $next` saying on `.slide.active` remove the `.active` class if its next sibling has the class `.slide`? If so how can you add a class to that?

Comment: Figured it out. Appreciate the help

Comment: See my answer, I tried to keep the original logic flow you have. But otherwise, @Yuschick has a better clean version. :-)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/gm9twq6j/

You should pass around a class called "active" using `.addClass`, `.removeClass`, and `.hasClass` instead of what you are trying to do with swapping out IDs.

JS:

```
function changeImage() {
    var active = $('#slideshow').find('.active');
    var first = $('#slideshow img:first-child');
    var last = $('#slideshow img:last-child');
    if ( last.hasClass('active') ) {
        var next = first;
    } else {
        var next = active.next();
    }
    active.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
}

setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow img {display: none;} 
#slideshow .active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <img class="active" src="https://i.imgur.com/8iOuvtf.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Wi8mlH2.jpg">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/MNhgqco.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use it more like

```
function changeImage() {
  var active = $("[state='active']");
  var next = active.is(":last") ? $("#slideshow:first-child") : active.next();
  active.data("state", "inactive"); //don't multiply same id attribute
  next.data("state", "active");
}

setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
```